# When will I need to serialize an object?

Tags: java, serialization

I recently watched a tutorial about serializing objects in java, but it left me wondering when can I use this?

From what I understand, the object is converted into a file, which can be converted back by another program, but could I not program the object into the other program? Please explain what this could be used for, thanks!

Comment: `"but could I not program the object into the other program"` What? Does that mean I have to re-program Microsoft Office every time I want to load a document?  Also think about network streams.

Comment: For example - could an office document not be saved as a code-based text file to be scanned into the program editing it, with a header giving font size and type information?
(But, of course this would not be ideal.)

So either way, the information is being saved for another program/network to be able to use it.

Comment: @CyberStorm your "code-based text file" is one type of serialization. Java's built-in serialization isn't the only way to have serialization - it's just there because it's much easier than writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
A user logs in to a game launcher , the launcher gets the user details and saves it as a serialized object.

When the user starts the game, the game looks for the file, gets the object and doesn't have to look online , that way the game starts much faster.

Hope you understand the use of it :)

Comment: Like saving user info for a login?

Comment: This is one example of use, you have many more, it's usefull when you make different programs use one object, in this example an user object